# HTML5 WebM streaming using chunks from FFMPEG via Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, webm, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to make use of websockets to livestream chunks from a WebM stream. The following is some example code on the server side that I have pieced together:

```
const command = ffmpeg()
  .input('/dev/video0')
  .fps(24)
  .audioCodec('libvorbis')
  .videoCodec('libvpx')
  .outputFormat('webm')

const ffstream = command.pipe()
ffstream.on('data', chunk => {
  io.sockets.emit('Webcam', chunk)
})
```

I have the server code structured in this manner so `ffstream.on('data', ...)` can also write to a file. I am able to open the file and view the video locally, but have difficulty using the chunks to render in a `<video>` tag in the DOM.

```
const ms = new MediaSource()
const video = document.querySelector('#video')
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms)
ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', function () {
  const sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"')
  // read socket
  // ...sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data)
})
```

I have something such as the above on my client side. I am able to receive the exact same chunks from my server but the `sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data)` is throwing me the following error:
`Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source`.

**Question: How can I display these chunks in an HTML5 video tag?**

*Note: From my reading, I believe this has to do with getting key-frames. I'm not able to determine how to recognize these though.*

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this or did you find another method that worked for your purpose?

Comment: @moeiscool nopes, I never did manage to get it working with **WebM** but I did [get it working](https://github.com/TimurKiyivinski/broccolli-preview) by streaming JPG instead.

Comment: ah, same here. I only got JPEG streaming also.